# Row height of grid based on the contents and other row visibility

Tags: wpf

I have a grid the row definitions are as following

```
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Now all the first three rows would be always visible but out of 4th and 5th row only one would be visible. How can I assign the row height property equally among all the four visible rows

Answer (score 0):

You can share the available `Height` equally between the top four rows like this:

```
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

However, if the last row is not visible, that sounds to me like the parent of the `Grid` is not set up correctly... you should always see *all* of the rows unless you have a problem. Is the `Grid` inside a `StackPanel` or Canvas`? I ask that because these containers do not adjust the size of their children like a`Grid` does and should only be used in certain situations.